# Multiple Value Conditions for DataTrigger

Tags: c#, wpf, datatrigger

I have a trigger list

```
<Style.Triggers>
    <DataTrigger Binding="{Binding Path=AddServerPanelVisible}" Value="True">
        <DataTrigger.EnterActions>
            <BeginStoryboard>
                <Storyboard>
                    <!-- Stuff -->
                </Storyboard>
            </BeginStoryboard>
        </DataTrigger.EnterActions>
    </DataTrigger>
    <DataTrigger Binding="{Binding Path=AddServerPanelVisible}" Value="False">
        <DataTrigger.EnterActions>
            <BeginStoryboard>
                <Storyboard>
                    <!-- Stuff -->
                </Storyboard>
            </BeginStoryboard>
        </DataTrigger.EnterActions>
    </DataTrigger>
</Style.Triggers>
```

But this isn't working. How could I take the same DataTrigger with different values? I want to have a different Storyboard for the True condition than for the False condition.

Comment: Does it work for at least one of the conditions?

Comment: Yes it works for False.

Comment: Could you include your view model?

Comment: Use the `DataTrigger.EnterActions` to trigger an animation when the bound value becomes `true`. Use  `DataTrigger.ExitActions` to trigger another animation when the bound value becomes `false`.

Comment: Huge Thanks @bitbonk. This works perfectly. Post this as an answer and I will approve it!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use the `DataTrigger.EnterActions` to trigger an animation when the bound value becomes `true`. Use `DataTrigger.ExitActions` to trigger another animation when the bound value becomes `false`.